# Pandas is not working after installing pandas it still giving module problem

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

The code is

```
import data as data
import pandas as pd
data
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Chitresh\Desktop\jkl.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame (data, colums = ['Roll'])
print(df)
```

And this is the problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chitresh\Desktop\LPU\python\objectoriented programming\csv.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\Chitresh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\Users\Chitresh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pandas.core.arrays import Categorical
  File "C:\Users\Chitresh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pandas.core.arrays.categorical import Categorical
  File "C:\Users\Chitresh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py", line 3, in <module>
    from csv import QUOTE_NONNUMERIC
  File "C:\Users\Chitresh\Desktop\LPU\python\objectoriented programming\csv.py", line 4, in <module>
    pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Chitresh\Desktop\jkl.csv')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I have tried some websites but cannot find what is wrong

Comment: How did you install pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Your python file is called `csv.py` and you're trying to read a `.cv`file. This can cause some problems like the `circular import`.
Change the name of your python file.
Probably you'll find the same problem if the call your python file `pandas.py`.

Edit:
As you edited your post, let me correct your code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Chitresh\Desktop\jkl.csv')
...
```

`import data as data` it's an unnecessary step. `pandas` has what you need to do what you want. Furthermore, when you import a module you don't need to add `as ...` if you will use the same name of the module. In your thrid line you've `data`but that variable isn't doing anything.